# Create a Mac OS X Style Dock Bar in Swing

Tags: java, macos, swing, user-interface, dock

I want to create a Mac OS X style Dock Bar to be placed at the bottom of a JFrame. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: This is a pretty open question. You need to clarify a few things.
1. Are you looking for a 3rd party API to do this for you?
2. Are you doing it from scratch?
3. What specific features of the Dock Bar interest you: drag & drop, mouse-over animations, expanding folders, bouncy icons?
4. What do you know? Are you starting with 0 knowledge? What don't you know, what is giving you trouble?

Comment: Are there any third-party APIs? I am mainly interested in the mouse-over animations and bouncy icons.

Comment: Animations and bouncy icons can be achieved with animation frameworks. Check out https://timingframework.dev.java.net/ and http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1090

Comment: both links are dead... any chance you have the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at second part of this presentation
http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2008/pdf/TS-4982.pdf?cid=925395

Comment: Know where I can get the full source code from (including icons)?

Comment: Get on Elie's blog (URL is on the last page of presentation) and leave him a message

Comment: this link isn't working anymore, anyone has the code?